# Laravel Cashier $user->subscriptions does not work after Cachier update

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

I updated Laravel to v8 and Cashier to v13. After that, When I'm trying to get user's subscriptions, it always gives the error 500:

> Undefined class constant
> 'Stripe\Subscription::PAYMENT_BEHAVIOR_ALLOW_INCOMPLETE'

I checked this constant - it's there. There is no such error if I go back to Laravel 5.8 and Cashier 10. What could happen?

Comment: Can you try calling any other constants? Try inside a `dd()`. Post the output here.

Comment: From that class - no. And what I've noticed - It's working via tinker.

Comment: Can you post the code? Along with the composer dependency?